# Test email and password for Quick Books API Oauth authentication

Tags: api, oauth, quickbooks

I want to test connecting to Quick Books  using their API. So I've set up everything I need. When I click on a button and it gets me to a page where I should enter an email and a password. I'd like to use their "test" email and password. But I didn't find any anything about that? Do they exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "test" username and password.

Either submit a support ticket to Intuit to get a free trial of QuickBooks Online, or just sign up for the 30-day QuickBooks Online free trial to test.